# In phpStorm IDE add keymapping to tools Window + extended Live Templates source

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, keymapping, live-templates

**1)** I've started to use Jetbrains phpStorm IDE, but I can't figure out how to add **the key mapping** to the **tools Windows**, so that I can see it on the side-bar and look at it any time. Now I have to navigate to File->settings->keymap. 
(Actually I've set Visual studio Key mapping  but in reality it differs from it even for basic operations.)

**2)** I would also like **attach an extended and "standard" kind of Live Template list**, which is right the after implementation pretty  slim.

**Sublime text** has pretty good .xml files for these (HTML, JQuery, JavaScript etc.) but I don't know if I can import/translate them somehow into phpStorm. I use Sublime quiet often (love it) and want to use it parallel with phpStorm. so it would be nice to have the same abbreviations in both.

*To answer the second option is not so important, I can figure it out, but to solve the first question I've spent half a day ferreting around the web.*

Comment: **1)** Not clear what you want / what problems you are having. I can assign different shortcut to a tool window (Project or Favourites, for example) **2)** You will have to do this manually (`Settings | Live Templates`) or by writing some converter tool yourself to automate this (from ST format to XML used by PhpStorm). You can find live templates in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde70\config\templates` folder (that's for PhpStorm v7 on Windows 7; for other OS -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Comment: for question 1) : I do not know how to attach a window other than the ones listed in View->Tool Windows. This is still unsolved. Actually I figured out that Ctrl+Shift+A brings up a quick open dialog, by typing keymap in there pops up the keymaps window, which is very usefull. For the second question I agree.

Comment: Meanwhile I asked the JetBrains forum, and the only solution is using the quick open dialog. Thanks for your help.